# android-Why android textview only shows one line

Tags: android, textview

this is my textview :

```
<TextView
    android:id="@+id/desc"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
    android:gravity="right"
    android:includeFontPadding="false"
    android:lineSpacingExtra="5dp"
    android:singleLine="false"
    android:textSize="15sp" >
</TextView>
```

The problem is that it only shows 1 lines and add ..... at the end of lines .

I want to use it as a description textview , so I don't know how many lines it could be .

How can I remove this limitation and make textview to get as many lines as it need ?

Comment: You'd better show the java file as well

Comment: @mahdi, did you find a working answer for this? I have the same problem. I already tried `android:maxLines="10"` but it doesn't help.

Answer (score 1):

Also you can try to add (with `maxLines="4"` or any other number instead of 4) 
`android:inputType="text"` 
You can set some other input types, but you should define one

Comment: Android Studio now says you should not use `android:inputType` with a `TextView`, it says to change it to an `EditText`.

Answer (score 0):

Try using min and max lines, i've put minLine to 1, and maxLine to n , where n is bigger than your biggest data.

```
<TextView
    android:id="@+id/desc"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
    android:gravity="right"
    android:includeFontPadding="false"
    android:maxLines="n"
    android:lines="1"
    android:textSize="15sp" >
</TextView>
```

Answer (score -1):

Use max lines or change the width.